# Can any other word have the form grow + adjective?

Tags: word-usage, predicative-complement

While reading some books, I came across this phrase.

> before Nate grows tired of walking in circles with me

And here's the whole paragraph.

> I break for the oak tree, dragging Nate behind me. I find an acorn,
> scoop it into my mouth, and run to the stash next to the garage. I
> place the acorn in the pile and run back to the tree. I grab another
> acorn; I bring it back to the stash. I place my third acorn in the
> pile before Nate grows tired of walking in circles with me. He leads
> me inside.

I realized that this means getting tired. But why is *grow* used to mean *get* here?

I heard *get + adjective* and *be or become + adjective* are only possible forms like this. Can any other such word have this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Grow* is a [linking verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb) here. Linking verbs often appear to be modified by an adjective, called the [predicative complement](https://magnumproofreading.com/blog/predicates/predicative-complement), instead of an adverb. The adjective actually modifies the subject of the sentence.

> *Nate* grows *tired*.

Here, *tired* describes *Nate*'s state. By contrast, in *Nate grew by six inches*, *by six inches* answers the question *How much?*, so it is an adverb.

There is a myriad of linking verbs. For example,

| Linking verb | Example with *tired* |
| --- | --- |
| become | Nate becomes tired |
| seem | Nate seems tired |
| feel | Nate feels tired |
| remain | Nate remains tired |

As you can see, the structure works with each of them. Therefore, *be*, *get*, and *grow* are **not** the only such words. Broadly, the structure is *subject + linking verb + complement*.

Here is the definition of *grow tired*, where *grow* is a linking verb.

> to gradually become tired
> — [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grow)